# Is there a way to add a reference subsection after each section?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, zotero

I'm using LibreOffice(Writer) + Zotero combo for my scientific writings. I'm recently writing a letter/conversation style document where I have several more or less independent sections. I was wondering if there's a way to add a separate reference (bibliography) subsection at the end of each section? For example:

> ## Section 1
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit[1]. Maecenas pretium, massa nec scelerisque congue, nisl ipsum dictum diam, a tincidunt arcu velit elementum erat[2]. Vivamus ornare, metus ac hendrerit dignissim, purus augue dictum orci, nec rhoncus nibh nunc nec est.
>
> ### Reference
>
> [1] C. Rawlings-Way, Lonely Planet New Zealand (Footscray Victoria: Lonely Planet, 14th edn., 2008), ISBN 1-74104-816-8, p. 52.
>
> [2] R. Unterberger, "The Band", and S. T. Erlewine, "Creedence Clearwater Revival", in Bogdanov et.al., 2002, pp. 61–2 and 265-6.
>
> ## Section 2
>
> Cras ullamcorper, magna non molestie consequat, mi enim aliquam est, et tincidunt turpis diam at nunc. Sed vitae ullamcorper enim, nec bibendum nulla[1]. In tellus lacus, ultricies id rhoncus in, aliquet at sapien. Ut eleifend laoreet magna eget varius. Nullam sit amet venenatis arcu, in euismod orci. Pellentesque laoreet, orci in tempus eleifend, velit enim vestibulum leo, sit amet ultricies lacus tortor ac sem[2]. Proin sed auctor odio, in dictum diam. In feugiat sagittis urna quis rhoncus.
>
> ### Reference
>
> [1] B. Hinton, "The Nitty Gritty Dirt Band", in P. Buckley, ed., Rock: The Rough Guide (London: Rough Guides, 1st edn., 1996), ISBN 1-85828-201-2, pp. 612–3.
>
> [2] E. Macan, Rocking the Classics: English Progressive Rock and the Counterculture (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1997), ISBN 0-19-509887-0, p. 64.

Answer (score 1):

There's no elegant solution. The only way to do this is to author the different sections in separate LibreOffice documents, and then, once you're done, remove Zotero field codes for each of the documents so that Zotero won't update the citations & numbers (the un-link button at the right of the LibreOffice add-on) and paste them into a single document.